# Chart.js custom tooltip at specifc points

Tags: charts, chart.js

I am using chart.js to build these charts. I want to add a custom message in tooltip only at points that has an image.

Example :

Here is what I have in all coordinates: This just displays the points of both series.

[image]

But I expect tool tips near image to be something like this which will have a custom message specific to the point

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by image? post your best try to achieve this

Comment: What about a tooltip callback? Something like: `if(x===imagePosition){return defaultText + additionalText)}`? The hover area is not linked to the image though...